# equiangular triangle and law of cosine

Tags: plane-geometry

How can I prove that Equiangular triangles are equilateral in plane geometry using Law of cosine? How is it that equiangular triangles are equilateral is a direct consequence of law of cosine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ápplying the law of cosines we obtain
$$a^2=b^2+c^2-bc$$
$$b^2=a^2+c^2-ac$$
$$c^2=a^2+b^2-ab$$
adding these equations we get
$$a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ac=0$$
and this is 
$$\frac{1}{2}\left((a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\right)=0$$
and this is what you want.

Comment: How did the cosine parts vanished?

Comment: That last bit should be $\frac{1}{2}\left((a-b)^2+(b-c) ^2+(c-a)^2\right)=0$

Comment: @jyotishrajthoudam Because $\cos 60^{\circ} = 0.5$

Comment: What if we are to assume that we are not given that all the angles are 60?

Comment: sorry it was a typo

Comment: There's still an error in the last term on the LHS. I'll edit to correct.

Comment: if we have given that not all angles are $60^{\circ}$ then the triangle isn't equilateral.

Comment: where is the error?

Comment: yes i have found it thank you it is early in morníng ing Germany

Comment: I've already edited it. Your sum of squared differences wasn't cyclic like it should've been.

Comment: But for the argument's sake if we are asked to prove it without the use of 60 degree?

Comment: but  the problems states that we have a equiangular triangle

Comment: Yes if we put a constant "k" instead of cos60?